# How long should a 'close' vote be allowed to brew?

Tags: discussion

Today I flagged a question for closure on the grounds that it was off-topic. I was the first to flag it. Within an hour or so, the question had been migrated to Stack Overflow. I subsequently heard that there *is* a Tridion context to the question, and perhaps with the normal process of comments asking the questioner to improve the relevance, we'd have ended up with a Q&A of value here on tridion.se

My expectation in setting the flag was not that a moderator would immediately agree with me and act on it, but that the community process would be allowed time to work. I ended up feeling like I'd had too much influence. Please note that this is not to point the finger at any specific moderator. (How bad a call can it be to agree with me?! :-) My point is that as a community we need to be clear about what our expectations are of moderators and their activities. If the upshot is that we expect moderators to act very quickly, I need to know that, because the knowledge should influence my flagging behaviour. My preference would be for moderators to err on the side of waiting too long, but that's my own view. I'm posting this here to see what others think.